# jQuery - get sibling's child

Tags: jquery

Currently my logic works like this, say I have a table:

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr class="row">
            <td class="title">Text</td>
            <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

jQuery:

```
$('.row :checkbox').click(function() {
    // do stuff
}).parents('.row').find('.title').click(function() {
    $(this).parent().find(':checkbox').trigger('click');
});
```

EDIT: My question is - the checkbox might sometimes be deeper in the tree, say inside 2 nested spand, etc. What's the best way to approach this? Like I did? Or is there something similar to `.siblings()` or `.parents()` that finds the closest element by looking in ancestor's children as well?

Comment: No, there are no `.nephew()` or `.cousin()` methods.

Comment: `$(this).next().find('input').trigger('change');`

Comment: Can you be more specific about *sometimes this gets deeper, like with inner divs, etc*?

Comment: @Barmar good idea, though, I chuckled and and at the same time thought about making a plugin for that :P

Comment: Apologies everyone, my question earlier wasn't clear. I have updated it

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
$(this).siblings().find(':checkbox').trigger('click');
```

This will work if the thing you're trying to find is always nested under a sibling, not one of the siblings themselves.

Answer (score 1):

Use `next`

```
$(this).next().find(':checkbox').trigger('click');
```

Comment: I think he's trying to generalize to more complex layouts, so the checkbox may not be under the next element.